# Issue with encoding; .jar doesn't work with Cyrillic characters in UTF-8 files

Tags: java, encoding

So I have this regex as String literal in my code:

```
private static final String FILE_PATTERN = "((\\s*\".*НЕКОТОРЫЕ СИМВОЛЫ .*\"\\R)([^\"].* (?!-)\\d+\\s*)+)+";
```

Also I have input test files in UTF-8 encoding.

And the problem is that when I test my program in IDE (IntelliJ IDEA in my case) everything is OK. Particularly, regex works with Cyrillic characters in test files.

But when I build my program (Maven) and tested .jar file with the same test files, it turned out that most likely regex won't work with Cyrillic characters.

Then I tested it again with file in Windows 1251 encoding and it worked.

So my question is - how can I make my .jar work with UTF-8 files, just like in IDE?

Thanks in advance.

---

[UPDATE1]

[two test files, one in UTF-8 and another in Windows 1251](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16Ob6IvByYdoAtxWhO7R4VjEHQoVXHGuE?usp=sharing)

I've tried to replace Cyrillic characters with \u codes like this:

```
private static final String FILE_PATTERN = "((\\s*\".*\\u041E\\u0442\\u0434\\u0435\\u043B .*\"\\R)([^\"].* (?!-)\\d+\\s*)+)+";
```

this doesn't work :(

---

[UPDATE2]

File processing starts like this:

```
static void processFile(String inputFile) {
    try {
        String fileStr = FileHandler.readFile(inputFile).toString();
        if (!FileParser.validateFile(fileStr)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, input file format is invalid");
            ...
```

File validating looks like this:

```
public class FileParser {
private static final String FILE_PATTERN = "((\\s*\".*Отдел .*\"\\R)([^\"].* (?!-)\\d+\\s*)+)+";

public static boolean validateFile(String fileStr) {
    return Pattern.compile(FILE_PATTERN).matcher(fileStr).matches();
}
...
```

File reading is very common I think:

```
public class FileHandler {
public static StringBuilder readFile(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    String temp;
    try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader((fileName)))) {
        while ((temp = r.readLine()) != null) {
            res.append(temp).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("Input file not found!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log exception
    }
    return res;
}
...
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with how the test files are encoded (or assumed to be encoded) in your different environments.  We would need to see a [mcve] to check that.

Comment: You may want to try using the Unicode representation with \uxxxx where xxxx is the Unicode hex-value for the charecter.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the Unicode Support section of this Documantation Page [Java Doc Pattern Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added two test files, one in UTF-8, and another in Windows 1251

Comment: @Skgland thx for advice, but it looks like it doesn't work :(

Comment: Test files alone do not make for a MCVE.  In this case, they don't even come close.  Follow the link in my initial comment for a description of what we ordinarily expect in that regard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger pardon, I thought you mean you want to see test files. I've added code snippets

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw some possibilities at the problem.

The classes FileReader and FileWriter use the default platform encoding, without overload for a specified encoding. I am not sure whether this is intended, but one of the alternatives:

```
public static StringBuilder readFile(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    String temp;
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    //Charset charset = Charset.fromName("Windows-1251");
    try (BufferedReader r = Files.newBufferedReader(fileName, charset)) {
        while ((temp = r.readLine()) != null) {
            res.append(temp).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("Input file not found!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log exception
    }
    return res;
}
```

Or:

```
String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
    return new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Then the **editor** encoding of the java sources must be the same encoding as that of the **javac compiler**. One can check this by using the `\uXXXX` ASCII representation of such special chars: if it then suddenly works, ...

You used two backslashes, but `\u0063` (letter `c`) works java source level, and in fact instead of `public class` you can write `publi\u0063 \u0063lass`.

```
private static final String FILE_PATTERN =
    "((\\s*\".*\u041E\u0442\u0434\u0435\u043B .*\"\\R)([^\"].* (?!-)\\d+\\s*)+)+";
```

Then there is the regular expression, that has two Unicode flags, `(?u)` and `(?U)` undermore for what a *letter* constitutes. That should not be a problem here.

Comment: I've tried to use Charset class, but looks like it doesn't help too...
Thank you anyway!